# How can I retrieve a memoryview's complete state information?

Tags: python, memoryview

I'm writing a serializer, and [`memoryview` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memory-views) are giving me trouble. I need to know all the attributes necessary to re-create an identical memoryview upon deserialization, but I can't figure out how to access them.

---

Imagine I have a memoryview like this:

```
data = b'0123456789'

mem = memoryview(data)[2:5]
```

I can access the original bytes object through the `obj` attribute:

```
>>> m.obj is data
True
```

But how can I get my hands on the indices `2` and `5`, i.e. the bounds of the memoryview?

I tried all the attributes listed in the documentation, but none of them seems to contain the information I need:

```
>>> mem.format
'B'
>>> mem.itemsize
1
>>> mem.shape
(3,)
>>> mem.ndim
1
>>> mem.strides
(1,)
>>> mem.suboffsets
()
```

How can I extract the bounds of the memoryview?